# Scrollview not working with Relative layout but no errors

Tags: android, scrollview

This is the code for the xml file with scrollview. There are no errors but it won't work. New to Android so any help is appreciated.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:onClick="HydrogenDetails"
        android:text="@string/Hydrogen" 
        android:background="@color/OtherNonMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:onClick="LithiumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Lithium"
        android:background="@color/AlkaliMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:onClick="SodiumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Sodium"
        android:background="@color/AlkaliMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:onClick="PotassiumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Potassium"
        android:background="@color/AlkaliMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:onClick="RubidiumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Rubidium"
        android:background="@color/AlkaliMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:onClick="CaesiumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Caesium"
        android:background="@color/AlkaliMetals"/>"

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="312dp"
        android:onClick="FranciumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Francium"
        android:background="@color/AlkaliMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="364dp"
        android:onClick="BerylliumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Beryllium"
        android:background="@color/AlkalineEarthMetals"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="416dp"
        android:onClick="MagnesiumDetails"
        android:text="@string/Magnesium"
        android:background="@color/AlkalineEarthMetals"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

No errors show up in eclipse its only when I try to run it that it stops working.
If I get rid of the scrollview the buttons near the bottom disappear. If anyone can suggest a fix or knows a different way of doing this help would be great.

Comment: Hey what's up? you did not mark any answer as correct. Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have `"` after b6 button

You can also replace those buttons with ListView.